# ListView Image not updating when item clicked

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am using a customised list view for a checklist. 
One image and some text is set with ArrayAdapter.
When the user clicks an item on the list I want to first delete the curret Image of a Image view set with a background resource in the XML, and replace with another drawable.

Firstly image does not disappear and secondly the image i am trying to set it too seems to appear randomly and sometimes not at all:

The onListItemClicked Method

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //  when a list item is clicked, first remove the XML set image  cross to a replace with tick on image view

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ImageView equitmentCrossed = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.iv_equitmentCheckList_Cross);
        equitmentCrossed.setBackgroundResource(0);
        //displayImage.setBackground(null);
        equitmentCrossed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tick);

    }//end onListItemClicked
```

The Array Addapter:

```
ArrayAdapter checklistadaptor = new ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, Integer>>(this,
            R.layout.checklist_row, R.id.tv_equimentChecklistName, equitmentAndImagesArray) {

    //over ride getView
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checklist_row, container, false);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_equimentChecklistName);
        Pair<String, Integer> item = getItem(position);
        title.setText(item.first);
        ImageView displayIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_equimentChecklist);
        displayIcon.setBackgroundResource(item.second);
        //title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.second, 0, 0, 0);
        return convertView;
    }
 };//end getView

 this.setListAdapter(checklistadaptor);
```

Comment: What is the point of calling `setBackgroundResource` in succession like that?

Comment: First call is to remove the current drawable defined in XML. Second is to replace with new drawable

Comment: So why not just replace it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a `ListActivity`? So when you call `this.findViewById()` in `onListItemClick()`, `this` refers to the `ListActivity` which contains multiple Views with the id `iv_equitmentCheckList_Cross` (one per entry). Android will usually return the first match. Try to change it to `v.findViewById(R.id.iv_equitmentCheckList_Cross)`. `v` should be the View that represents the row.

Comment: Thanks, getting the image view with v.findViewById changes the image for the item clicked but also Images belonging to list items only visible as u scroll down the list! Also the setBackGround(null) not removing the previous image set in XML